# How to change vue-cookie-law default Props

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to change `buttonText` default value of the component vue-cookie-law with Props.

I can change the default value directly from the node_modules plugin source code, but I would like to change it from a Vue Single File Component.

vue-cookie-law - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookie-law

prop default type
buttonText: 'Got It!'

Since I haven't used Props before, I've been trying few things, below is my CookieLaw.vue component

```
<template>
  <footer>
    <cookie-law theme="base">
      <div slot="message">
        We use cookies to enhance your experience. By continuing to visit our site you agree to our use of cookies.
        <router-link to="terms_and_conditions">View Policy</router-link>
      </div>
    </cookie-law>
  </footer>
</template>

<script>
import CookieLaw from "vue-cookie-law";

export default {
  props: {
    buttonText: {
      default: "Agree"
    }
  },
  components: { CookieLaw }
};
</script>
```

The props are not changing the default of `buttonText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buttonText` is one of the default props for the `vue-cookie-law` component as you know ... not the parent component (the one that you import it on ) so you have to bind them to the component it self :

```html
  <cookie-law theme="base" buttonText="Agree">
       ...
  </cookie-law>
```

Or bind a dynamic value :

```js
<script>
  import CookieLaw from "vue-cookie-law";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: 'Agree'
    }
  }
  components: {
    CookieLaw
  }
}; <
</script>
```

```html
<cookie-law theme="base" :buttonText="text">
  ...
</cookie-law>
```